# Xen Hypervisor interdomain communication

Tags: virtual-machine, xen, hypervisor

In xen, we can achieve Interdomain communication using libvchan.

But, in domU, when starting communication, it's showing following error:

> libxenvchan_*_.init: no such file or directory.

For that I tried to mount /proc/xen/ with xenfs. It gives error as

> unknown file system "xenfs"

How to resolve this error above and how to achieve the Interdomain communication?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like "libxenvchan_*_.init: no such file or directory error" is a common problem. I did not find the solution doing web searches.

For me the solution on a linux system (CentOS 6.5) guest VM was to load the xen kernel modules
xen_gntalloc and xen_evtchn for a libvchan server. For a libvchan client it should be xen_gntalloc and xen_gntdev. Obviously this means that your guest VM has to be running a xen linux kernel. Note that I'm using xen 4.2.2 and the kernel is 3.4.53-8.el6.centos.alt.x86_64.

I found the specific problem by adding print statements to the source of the libxenctrl and libxenvchan libraries until I located the files that it could not find which turned out to be /dev/xen/gntalloc (server and client), /dev/xen/evtchn (server), /dev/xen/gntdev (client).

Comment: For those who arrived here looking for a command to run: `modprobe xen_gntalloc`, `modprobe xen_evtchn`, and `modprobe xen_gntdev`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the libraries required for vchan are properly installed. You can use the ldd command on your vchan-client binary to see if it could successfully load the required libraries.

Building and installing the Xen tools (make build-tools && make install-tools) in my guest VM (Debian 8.4.0 64-Bit) and executing ldconfig afterwards was sufficient to get the vchan example programms running.

I also had to load the Xen kernel modules mentioned in the previous answer.